# Debug GHC compilation error returned at runtime by hint's `Language.Haskell.Interpreter.runInterpreter`

Tags: haskell, ghc, hint

### [I've re-posted this question to focus more tightly on the specific error, and to better enumerate what I've already tried.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59495357/hint-interpret-gives-a-compiler-error-when-used-on-a-polysemy-sem-value)

I'm trying to parse some Haskell code during the runtime of a Haskell program using the [hint package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-0.9.0.2).

The outer program compiles, but when I run it the inner compilation step fails. I'm getting a description of what I assume is a syntax problem, and a location in the "interactive" code, but I have no idea how to view the code in question.

Here's Main.hs

```hs
module Main where

import Data.List (intercalate)
import Polysemy (runM)
import qualified Language.Haskell.Interpreter as H

import qualified Effects as E

handleFailures :: Either H.InterpreterError a -> IO a
handleFailures (Left l) = ioError $ userError $ message l
  where
    message (H.WontCompile es) = intercalate "\n" (header : map unbox es)
    message e = show e
    header = "ERROR: Won't compile:"
    unbox (H.GhcError e) = e
handleFailures (Right a) = return a

interpretation :: String -> H.Interpreter E.MyEffect
interpretation s = do
  H.loadModules ["Effects"]
  H.setImportsQ [("Prelude", Nothing), ("Effects", Nothing)]
  effect <- H.interpret s (H.as :: E.MyEffect)
  return effect

extractProgram :: String -> IO E.MyEffect
extractProgram s = do
  p <- H.runInterpreter $ interpretation s
  success <- handleFailures p
  return success

main :: IO ()
main = do
  userProvided <- readFile "UserProvided.hs"
  userProgram <- extractProgram userProvided
  runM . E.teletypeToIO . E.teletypePlusToIO $ userProgram
```

Effects.hs defines and provides helpers for a Polysemey `Sem` monad called `MyEffect`.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase, BlockArguments #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, FlexibleContexts, TypeOperators, DataKinds, PolyKinds, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Effects where

import Polysemy

data Teletype m a where
  ReadTTY  :: Teletype m String
  WriteTTY :: String -> Teletype m ()

makeSem ''Teletype

teletypeToIO :: Member (Embed IO) r => Sem (Teletype ': r) a -> Sem r a
teletypeToIO = interpret $ \case
  ReadTTY      -> embed getLine
  WriteTTY msg -> embed $ putStrLn msg

data TeletypePlus m a where
  ReadPlus  :: TeletypePlus m String
  WritePlus :: String -> TeletypePlus m ()

makeSem ''TeletypePlus

teletypePlusToIO :: Member (Embed IO) r => Sem (TeletypePlus ': r) a -> Sem r a
teletypePlusToIO = interpret $ \case
  ReadPlus      -> embed $ ("+" <>) <$> getLine
  WritePlus msg -> embed $ putStrLn $ msg <> "+"

type MyEffect = Sem [TeletypePlus, Teletype, Embed IO] ()
```

UserProvided.hs contains a simple `do` expression in `MyEffect`.

```hs
do
  i <- readTTY
  j <- readPlus
  let k = i <> j
  writeTTY k
  writePlus k
```

In order to get the polysemy package available at runtime, I have to enter run it from inside a cabal sandbox.

```
$ cabal build
    Build profile: -w ghc-8.8.1 -O1
    In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
     - Hello-Polysemy-0.1.0.0 (exe:Hello-Polysemy) (file Main.hs changed)
    Preprocessing executable 'Hello-Polysemy' for Hello-Polysemy-0.1.0.0..
    Building executable 'Hello-Polysemy' for Hello-Polysemy-0.1.0.0..
    [2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, /home/mako/Git/Hello-Polysemy/dist-newstyle/buil/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.8.1/Hello-Polysemy-0.1.0.0/x/Hello-Polysemy/build/Hello-Polysemy/Hello-Polysemy-tmp/Main.o )
    Linking /home/mako/Git/Hello-Polysemy/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.8.1/Hello-Polysemy-0.1.0.0/x/Hello-Polysemy/build/Hello-Polysemy/Hello-Polysemy ...
$ cabal exec bash
```

... but then ...

```
$ cabal run
    Up to date
    Hello-Polysemy: user error (ERROR: Won't compile:
    <interactive>:10:135: error:
        Operator applied to too few arguments: :)
```

So far as I can tell the *only* place I'm using the `:` operator is in Effects.hs, where (a) I'm actually using the type-operator `':`, and (b) compilation succeeds just fine when Effects is imported into Main.hs.

Any suggestions for what the problem might be, or how I could learn more?

I already tried using `Language.Haskell.Interpreter.Unsafe.unsafeRunInterpreterWithArgs ["-v4"]`. That clarifies that it's talking about `ghc-prim:GHC.Types.:{(w) d 66})`, but I don't know what to do with that information.

#### Update:

I've tried various permutations of in-lining the "userProvided" code.
declaring the exact same `Effect` value inline in Main works fine. Replacing the string read from the file with an inline string of an even simpler value `"writePlus \"asdf\""` doesn't change the error message.

Comment: Can you show us the program you’re trying to run using Hint? It may be that the error is in there rather than your main program.

Comment: @bradrn: edited to include the two referenced files.

Comment: I should clarify that the code presented is _supposed to be_ a proof-of-concept for a _different_ question I'm struggling with relating to Polysemey.

Comment: Have you checked that `UserProvided.hs` compiles on its own? Hint may just be reporting a compilation error.

Comment: UserProvided.hs is not a proper program or module; it's a snippet that's supposed to represent a value of type `MyEffect`. So I can't really "compile" it, but I can copy-paste it into GHCi with Effects loaded, and that works. I can even "run" it if I also import Polysemy!

Comment: I know that. What I was wondering is: _if_ you put that snippet into its own module, and import the necessary modules, does that compile?

Comment: I see. Yes: If I inline it in Main, wrapped in parentheses and indented with an explicit type-declaration as `E.MyEffect`, it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks @ShapeOfMatter! Then that can’t be the problem. I’ll have a closer look at the code and see if I can spot anything.

Comment: I’ve just discovered something very interesting: simply doing `H.interpret "pure ()" (H.as :: Sem '[Embed IO] ())` is enough to trigger the error! But I still don’t know what that error indicates, or how to fix it…